# Uniform convergence of bounded functions $f_n$ to $f^*$ implies boundedness of $f^*$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $(f_n)$ be a function sequence on $D \subset \mathbb R$ with $f_n \to f^*$ uniform on $D$. Assume $f_n$ bounded for all $n$.

I want to prove the following:

$f^*$ is bounded and 
$$
 \| f_n \|_\infty \to \| f^* \|_\infty, \quad \sup_{x \in D} f_n(x) \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \sup_{x \in D} f^*(x)\,.
$$

---

What I have done thus far;

We have that $f_n(x)$ is bounded for each $n \in \mathbb N$. Therefore, for all $n \in \mathbb N$ we can find a $M \in \mathbb R$ (possibly depending on $n$) such that for all $x \in D$ we have
$$
|f_n(x)| < M_n\,.
$$
As $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f^*$ on $D$, we have
$$
 \forall_{\epsilon > 0}\exists_{n^* \in \mathbb N}\forall_{n\geq n^*}\forall_{x\in D}: |f_n(x) - f^*(x)| < \epsilon\,.
$$

We shall first show that $f^*$ is bounded, therefore we need to prove that there exists an $M^* \in \mathbb R$ such that for all $x \in D$ we have
$$
 |f^*(x)| < M^*\,.
$$

To this end, take $\epsilon = 1$, then for $n \geq n^*$ we have that for all $x \in D$
\begin{align*}
 |f_n(x) - f^*(x)| < 1 \iff |f^*(x) - f_n(x)| &< 1\\
 \therefore -1 < f^*(x) - f_n(x) &< 1 \\
 \therefore -1 + f_n(x) < f^*(x) &< 1 + f_n(x) 
 \qquad \mbox{but $|f_n(x)| < M_n$, hence} \\
 \therefore -1 - M_n < f^*(x) &< 1 + M_n \iff |f^*(x)| < 1 + M_n\,.
\end{align*}

Now we have that $f^*$ is bounded by a quantity depending on $n \geq n^*$, which I assume is not enough. At this point I did some research and found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524161/is-uniform-convergent-sequence-leads-to-bounded-function) link, which basically says this is sufficient. However, when looking at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359102/show-uniform-convergence-of-bounded-functions-implies-uniform-boundness) link, I would suspect my proof is not enough and we want a value in $\mathbb R$ that bounds $f^*$ independent of any $x$ or $n$.

N.B. I haven't started the second part of the proof yet.

Comment: The answer given in the question [space of bounded continuous functions is complete](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71121/space-of-bounded-continuous-functions-is-complete) should help.

Comment: @parsiad I understand that this is a valid proof, but is a bound depending $n$ also sufficient, as described in my proof?

Comment: You're close. For $n \geq n^*$, we know $|f^*(x)-f_n(x)|<1$. Therefore, $|f^*(x)-f_{n^*}(x)|<1$, from which $|f^*(x)|<1+|f_{n^*}(x)|<1+M_{n^*}$ follows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @parsiad for his/her comment.

For $n \geq n^*$ we have $|f_n(x) - f^*(x)| < 1$, therefore
$$
  |f_{n^*}(x) - f^*(x)| < 1 \implies |f^*(x)| < 1 + |f_{n^*}(x)| < 1 + M_{n^*}
$$